# Spring Boot SSL - text cert to keystore

Tags: spring-boot, ssl

I ordered a SSL paid certificate for my Spring Boot app. What I recived is a text:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEsTCCA5mgA
....
JKAHSD823kjsd
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

What should I do with it? All Spring Boot SSL examples shows 'self-signed-certificate' generated with keytool as a file to place in projects classpath.
How to generate a p12 keystore from what I got?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pem format ([refer this](https://community.arubanetworks.com/t5/Controller-Based-WLANs/How-do-I-find-out-if-my-X-509-certificate-is-in-PEM-DER-or/ta-p/177996)) , and then convert it your desired format using openssl utilities ([refer this](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html))